# How to catch SQL error in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I need to catch and process error, when i try to remove entity from db.

> [Error deleting record: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zdf`.`cats`, CONSTRAINT `FK_cats_Categories` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)]

i try to remove entity by button click in with "deleteURL"

```
  $dbCategories = new Application_Model_DbTable_Categories();
    $source = new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Select($dbCategories->getCategoriesByAppId(1, true));
        $columns = array('title', 'actions');
        $columnsPositions = array('title');
        $extraColumns = array(
            0 => $this->createExtraColumn(array(
                'name' => 'actions',
                'position' => 'right',
                'title' => 'Actions',
                'decorator' => '<a class="edit-button" href="{{editUrl}}">&nbsp;</a><a class="remove-button" href="{{deleteUrl}}">&nbsp;</a>'
            ))
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find how to catch this error with ZF DataGrid without doing something in the component library, I've made delete by myself depending on URL params.

Basicly,

```
$deleteId =  $this->getRequest()->getParams('Delete');
```

then `Try...Catch` block with `$model->delete($id);`

and manually handle exception.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Try/Catch block?

```
try {
    $dbCategories = new Application_Model_DbTable_Categories();
    $source = new Bvb_Grid_Source_Zend_Select($dbCategories->getCategoriesByAppId(1, true));
    $columns = array('title', 'actions');
    $columnsPositions = array('title');
    $extraColumns = array(
        0 => $this->createExtraColumn(array(
            'name' => 'actions',
            'position' => 'right',
            'title' => 'Actions',
            'decorator' => '<a class="edit-button" href="{{editUrl}}">&nbsp;</a><a class="remove-button" href="{{deleteUrl}}">&nbsp;</a>'
        ))
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle exception here...
}
```

Comment: tried... doesn't catch it there...i understand that it should be like that, but can't figure out where should be this try catch block... this confuses me.

Comment: Interesting.  Is it being thrown as a regular PHP error, not an exception?  How about using `set_error_handler()` to catch all PHP errors and throw them as exceptions instead?  I do this on all my projects.